# How to sync the tab widget with a push button

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtwidgets

I am fairly new and unfamiliar with QT and was wondering how you could sync  a pushbutton with the tab widget. What I am trying to accomplish is for the user to able to click a button “next” and be able to be taken to the next tab. It’s turning out to be more difficult than I thought. Please give detailed instructions if able because like I said before, I’m not too familiar with QT.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
              ui->tabWidget;
           int count = tabWidget.count();
           int currentTab=tabWidget.currentIndex();

    if (currentTab == count - 1){
        //tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
        tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0);
        tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(currentTab+1);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get currently active tab index and increment it. But you also have to decide what if the current tab is the last one. Should you go to the first one or do nothing ? A schematic code would look like this (next tab goes to first if out of range).

**EDIT:** I made a quick example myself, and this code works for me.

```
void Form::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int count = ui->tabWidget->count();
    int currentTab = ui->tabWidget->currentIndex();
    if (currentTab == count - 1)
        ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(currentTab+1);
}
```

Comment: I tried to execute this code. I replaced the -> with dots. For some reason it wont work, but it does compile. QTabWidget tabWidget;  int count = tabWidget.count();  int currentTab=tabWidget.currentIndex(); if (currentTab == count - 1){  tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0); (currentTab+1); tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(currentTab+1);

Comment: The tabWidget has to be the one that already exists in your ui, not new object

Comment: I assume to create a object from the widget I’m using, I have to “go to a slot”. There are a many options like tabBarClicked, destroyed(int). I’m sorry to as a lot of you. I’m just trying to figure out what it is I need to do to create an object with a tab widget I’ve done this only with a push button and that was how I did it.

Comment: In the designer create a tabWidget and button, click right on button go to slot; clicked() and there paste the code. Instead of tabWidget write something like `ui->tabWidget`

Comment: That's what I did because it made the most sense. It now giving me errors.( error: C2228: left of '.count' must have class/struct/union type is ''unknown-type''). I’m not understanding why. I believe when you create a slot it automatically make a class.

Comment: I will need more code, you can edit your answer and paste some?

Comment: I have posted the code in my question. Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: @user3878223 Not a problem, glad I could help. If you don't mind please accept my answer (under the vote).